# Can't get audio files from external storage - Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, mediastore, android-cursor, android-external-storage

I'm following this guide in creating an audio player:
https://www.sitepoint.com/a-step-by-step-guide-to-building-an-android-audio-player-app/.
The problem occurs when I try to find the audio files. After creating cursor it's not null but using cursor.getCount() the result is 0, so no audio were found. Audio files can't be found both on the phone and on the emulator. When i was looking for a solution i came across some other contentResolver.query, but that seems not to be the problem.
I used this in my manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And that is method to find audio files:

```
private void loadAudio() {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "!= 0";
        String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC";
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, selection, null, sortOrder);
        boolean cursorB = cursor == null;
        Log.d("aaaaaa", "uri" + uri.toString());
        Log.d("aaaaaa", "cursor.getCount() " + cursor.getCount() + " " + cursorB);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            audioList = new ArrayList<>();
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                @SuppressLint("Range") String data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
                @SuppressLint("Range") String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
                @SuppressLint("Range") String album = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
                @SuppressLint("Range") String artist = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));

                Log.d("aaaaaa", "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
                // Save to audioList
                audioList.add(new Audio(data, title, album, artist));
            }
        }
        Log.d("Song", "Song:" + audioList.get(0).getTitle());
        cursor.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something to work with

`@SuppressLint("Range")` can go at the top of the method, no need to repeat in code lines
`cursor.getCount()` will crash if `cursor == null`

```
private final String track_id = MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID;
private final String bucket_displayname = MediaStore.Audio.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME;
private final String track_no = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TRACK;
private final String track_name = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE;
private final String artist = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST;
private final String artist_id = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST_ID;
private final String duration = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION;
private final String album = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM;
private final String composer = MediaStore.Audio.Media.COMPOSER;
private final String year = MediaStore.Audio.Media.YEAR;
private  String path = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA;
private final String date_added = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED;
private final String genre = MediaStore.Audio.Media.GENRE;
private final String genre_id = MediaStore.Audio.Media.GENRE_ID;

public Cursor getAllTracks(Context context) {
    // gets all tracks
    if (context != null) {
        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
        String[] columns =null;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.Q ) {
            columns = new String[]{track_id, track_no, artist, track_name,
                    album, duration, path, year, composer, genre, genre_id};
        }else{
            columns = new String[]{track_id, track_no, artist, track_name,
                    album, duration, path, year, composer};
        }
        Uri uri = uris.get_audio_media_uri();
        Cursor crs=cr.query(uri, columns, null, null, null);
        enumerateAndrodCursor(context, crs);
        return crs;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

public Uri get_audio_media_uri(){
    Uri uri_to_use = null;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        uri_to_use = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL);
    } else {
        uri_to_use = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    }
    return uri_to_use;
}

public void enumerateAndrodCursor(Context context, @NonNull Cursor c) {
    try {
        if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
            for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
                // String id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(pampfolder_playlist_entries_id));
                String strartist = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
                String stralbum = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
                String strtitle = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TRACK));
                String strdisplay_name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String strplaylistentry = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID));

                Log.i("ABC", "trackid = " + strplaylistentry+ " Artist = " + strartist + " Album = " + stralbum + " Title = " + strtitle+ " display_name ="+ strdisplay_name);

            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```